# Form action is refreshing the html page on being live on domain

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 25px;"> </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" 
       name="login_user">Login</button>
  </div>
    </div>
</form>


if (isset($_POST['login_user']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM portal_users WHERE username='$username' 
    AND password_2='$password' and user_status ='1'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

         getEmpDetail($results);
            header('location: index.php');
        } 
    }
}
```

I have used ob_start() but it didn't gave he desired effect it just keep on refreshing the page and so on.
is the form implementation faulty or i am using header in php doestnt wotk in php v 5.2.

Comment: use [`session`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)  to detect the page already login or not

Comment: Don't use MD5 for password encryption. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: still i cant stop from page being refresh and cant get it to redirect to index.php after login

Comment: it turn out you need to set index as main page so i put the login functionality in index and then redirect it its working fine